# Scrollview in Xcode6

Tags: autolayout, xcode6

Scrollview in Xcode6 is ridiculing me a bit.

I have added a scrollview, and a content view inside the scroll view.

The content view has some various sub views.

My problem is with the new layout in Xcode where it's the w Any by h Any - adaptive layout or what they call it.

The problem is that the content view is suddenly 600 pixels wide so I get some horizontally scrolling, which I do not want.

I simply want the content view's size to be as wide as the device.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh - I found the answer. Simply add a constraint making the scroll view and content view the same width.